# By using this function i am not able to populate my mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

This is the code......

```js
app.post('/create-contact',function(req,res){
  Contact.create().then(function(newContact){
        ({name:req.body.name, 
        phone:req.body.phone});
        console.log('*******************',newContact);
        return res.redirect('back');
    }).catch(function(err,newContact){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error in creating the contact!");
            return;
        }
    });
```

that newContact is getting null... I am getting the value in req.body.name and `req.body.phone` but it isn't getting stored in `newContact` and not updated in DB

Comment: The connection to database is ok? Can you show related code?

Answer (score 0):

You are using parenthesis instead of curly braces to define the properties of the newContact object. Replace the parenthesis with curly braces and check.
Like this:

```
Contact.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    phone: req.body.phone
}).then(function(newContact){

console.log('*************',newContact);
    return res.redirect('back');
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("Error in creating 
the contact!", err);
    return res.status(500).send("Error creating
contact");
});
```

Moreover, make sure that the Contact model has the correct schema and is properly connected to your MongoDB database.